# gitlab local docker instance: "vboxmanage": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: gitlab, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I used

```
  docker run --rm -it -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

to install a virtualbox runner on my gitlab which also runs on docker. My host computer has access to the command `vboxmanage`, but the CI gives this error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: exec: "vboxmanage": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Could it be possible that it's trying to access `vboxmanage` from inside the container and thus not finding it? If yes, then how can I access vboxmanage from non docker?

Comment: Dear @Guerlando OCs, Was the Docker runner registration successful (`docker run … gitlab/gitlab-runner register`)? Please, refer to the documentation section: [Docker | Registering runners | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker). Please, note the steps: #7 and #8. Additionally, when does the error (`ERROR: Preparation failed`) occur: for instance, when a runner registration is performed or a build is triggered?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov happens when the build is triggered, and yes, docker registration worked. I believe the docker image has no access to the vboxmanager binary which is outside docker